# Understanding inverse trigonometric relations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

[image]

Can someone explain why the inverse trig functions are trapped between those particular numbers.

Comment: They're not really, that's just what the calculator will spit out. Those intervals are auxiliary angles. It's like saying $\sin(30)=\sin(150)$.

Comment: Why is cosines reference angle able to go up to 180 then

Comment: Depending on how much you know, there are different answers to this question. The simplest way I can answer is that if you draw these trigonometric functions, you will realize within these domains, no y value is being repeated. If you would like to know more, you can look up one-to-one correspondence.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions